# Open R console in its original way, not in linux terminal

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and have installed R long time ago. Every time I open the R, a linux terminal window (with R console incorporated inside) will pop out. I want to go back to the original R console (not in the linux terminal window). Could anyone tell me how to do that?
Thanks~

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. I'm guessing you're coming from Windows an think RGui is universal or that you've tried RStudio and think that's the default way to interact with R? Neither is correct.

Comment: You are right, I used R in Windows before. I am thinking if I can open R in a similar GUI like Windows RGui in Ubuntu. So there is no such thing in Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Have you tried Rstudio?

Comment: Yes. I installed RStuido. I was thinking if there is a similar RGui in linux, like the one in Windows (the GUI after you install R, no other IDE).

Comment: Not really. Is there an issue with using the terminal if you don't want to use rstudio?

Comment: RStudio is good. But sometimes I just want to run a few lines code (~20 lines) and do not want to open the RStudio. The Windows RGUI can create r script and run code line by line to see the result in the console. The linux terminal window is not that convenient, especially when you write function and want to edit the code. Maybe I am not good at using the linux terminal. I just switched to the linux OS.

Comment: Use case: I work for a huge HPC facility, we have two clusters, one is a top100 supercomputer. Researchers use R a lot and RStudio is not an option as we are not going to use a dedicated node for that (it can't just run in the batch nodes). I would love to have a GUI that could be used with ssh -X for our not-so-savvy users and for which we would not need to to extra work and create an EasyConfig, if possible. Hence that I landed here :)
Jupyter Notebooks is a good option though and VSStudio Code.